# Ordering posts by comment count in the last x hours

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this code, which is kind of doing what I want, but there's something it's still missing:

```
    <?php 
    $hours = 12;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT p.comment_count, p.ID, p.post_title
    FROM $wpdb->posts p
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->comments c ON c.comment_post_ID = p.ID
    WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND ( TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, c.comment_date, NOW() ) <= %d )
    GROUP BY p.ID
    ORDER BY p.comment_count DESC
    LIMIT 0, 6
    ", $hours ) );
        
        
         foreach ($result as $topten) {
             $postid = $topten->ID;
             $title = $topten->post_title;
             $commentcount = $topten->comment_count;
             if ($commentcount != 0) {
      ?>
```

Basically, I want to order 6 posts which has the most comments in the last 12 hours.

What the above code should do is this:

Let's say there are these posts that have the most comments in the last 12 hours:

```
Apple (10 comments), 
Orange (8 comments), 
Banana (7 comments), 
Cherry (5 comments), 
Lemon (3 comments), 
Grape (2 comments).
```

Theoretically, they should be ordered in the above order.

However, the interesting part is that.

Even if Grape has 2 comments and should be last, but since ALL TIME it has the most comments, It will order as first:

```
Grape (2 comments), 
Apple (10 comments), 
Orange (8 comments) and etc.
```

Which is not correct.

Basically, it doesn't matter if Apple has 10 comments, as soon as you write at least 1 comment in Grape post, it will put Grape as first.

In other words, somehow the above code knows which fruits have the most comments (ALL TIME), and put them in that order, regardless of the time frame you set and how many comments it received during that time.

Same happens with all other ALL TIME posts with most comments.

Let's say ALL TIME is this:

```
Grape (300 comments), 
Lemon (200 comments), 
Cherry (200 comments)
```

with the above code, if it gets (in the last 12 hours):

```
Cherry (3 comments), 
Lemon (2 comments), 
Grape (1 comment), 
Apple (30 comments), 
Orange (20 comments).
```

it will order like this:

```
Grape,  
Lemon, 
Cherry, 
all other depending on the ALL TIME.
```

Even though, Apple should be the first one in the line.

I hope I'm explaining in a clear manner.

I know I'm making a mistake somewhere in the code.

I'm not a coder.

Desperately need help.

Comment: So, you only want to show posts that got comments in the last twelve hours? And of all these posts you want to show the six that have most comments in the database? What about ties? If you have Grape (300), Lemon (200), Cherry (200), Apple(200), Strawberry (200), Peach (100), and Banana (100), will you show Peach and Banana or pick one of the two arbitrarily or show only five fruits then? What is your DBMS? When asking SQL questions (and this is about `sql` and not about `php` and not about `database`), you should tag the request with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Yes, to show 6 posts (and order them by popularity) those who got the most comments in the last 12 hours.

As for ties, show both (peach and banana), but the order doesn't matter. They could rotate between the places.

Sorry, what is DBMS?

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: DBMS is MySQL for instance. Or SQL Server. Or Oracle. Or PostgreSQL. You tagged `mysql` now, so you are obviously using MySQL :-) Which version are you using? Things have become easier with MySQL 8.

Comment: MySQL version: 5.6.47

Comment: That is a very old version that isn't even supported anymore. Consider upgrading to MySQL 8.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the six posts with the most comments within the last twelve hours. Use `IN` (or `EXISTS`) for that.

You want to order posts by their overall comment count. You can order by a subquery.

```
SELECT p.comment_count, p.id, p.post_title
FROM posts p
WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND p.id IN
(
  SELECT c.comment_post_id
  FROM comments c
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, c.comment_date, NOW() ) <= 12
  GROUP BY c.comment_post_id
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 6
)
ORDER BY
(
  SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0)
  FROM comments c
  WHERE c.comment_post_id = p.id
) DESC;
```

The problem with this is that this doesn't account for ties. It will arbitrarily pick one post to be the sixth if there are several with the same count. In order to deal with this replace the `IN` clause:

```
AND p.id IN
(
  SELECT top6_and_ties.comment_post_id
  FROM comments top6_and_ties
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, top6_and_ties.comment_date, NOW() ) <= 12
  GROUP BY top6_and_ties.comment_post_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) IN
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM comments top6_counts
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, top6_counts.comment_date, NOW() ) <= 12
    GROUP BY top6_counts.comment_post_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 6
  )
)
```

In your PHP script this goes probably here:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT p.comment_count, p.id, p.post_title
FROM posts p
WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND p.id IN
(
  SELECT top6_and_ties.comment_post_id
  FROM comments top6_and_ties
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, top6_and_ties.comment_date, NOW() ) <= %d
  GROUP BY top6_and_ties.comment_post_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) IN
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM comments top6_counts
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, top6_counts.comment_date, NOW() ) <= %d
    GROUP BY top6_counts.comment_post_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 6
  )
)
ORDER BY
(
  SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0)
  FROM comments c
  WHERE c.comment_post_id = p.id
) DESC
", $hours , $hours ) );
```

Comment: I'm not a coder, could you simply paste the code with <?php  ?>. Just like mine above. I have tried put your code into mine, and getting errors. I have no idea where to put it. Where is the start and where's the end. And whether any kind of part of my code is still required... thanks in advance Thorsten.

Comment: I'm not using PHP much. I've edited my answer and hope this works. There may be errors in my code of course. If you are not a coder then why do you code?